# Disallow particular cell to stretch

Tags: jgraph, mxgraph

How to disallow particular cell to stretch ? 
"graph.setCellsResizable(false)" There are methods for all cells, how to apply it to a particular cell.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `resizable=0;` to the style of that cell.

Answer (score 1):

**By adding custom styles we can stop resizing and moving of vertex**

First initialize style object

```
var style = new Object();
style[mxConstants.STYLE_RESIZABLE] = '0';
```

Then add style in graph stylesheet

```
graph.getStylesheet().putCellStyle('resizableLock', style);
```

Then plot vertex with the custom style name

```
var v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent,'1233','Hello',20,50,100,100,'resizableLock');
```